# "CreateFromDirectory" with "4" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."

Tags: .net, powershell-3.0

I am trying to zip folders for one moth to a single file. for example 201501  is for all folders for jan and I need to zip  to a file called somename-2015-jan.zip. all other logic is working only zipplig part showing the above error. I have powershell v3 and ,net 4.54 ,  something wrong when i can calling  System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory  to compress file.

```
                  $year = 2015  
              $base = "D:\Archive\"


              $folder = Get-Content "D:\Archive\MasterFolder.txt"
                          #write-host $folder.count total lines read from file
                          foreach ($Fname in $folder)
                          {

                  $yearmonth = Get-Content "D:\Archive\duration.txt"
                                      write-host $yearmonth.count total lines read from file
                                      foreach ($date in $yearmonth)
                  {


            $source = "$base$Fname\$date*"


            #[string]$text = "$date"    

            $string = $date
            #201501
            $mmd = $string.Substring(4,2)
                Write-host "fffcmd $mmd"


            if ($mmd -gt 12) {
                "$mmd is bigger than 12 Which is not valid,Please Correct The file name durations.txt and run the command again"
                 break
                        } 

Else {

write-host " This is Source Folder Name !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$source"
switch($mmd) 
    { 
    "01" {$mm = "jan"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}

    "02" {$mm = "Feb"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}

   "03" {$mm = "Mar"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "04" {$mm = "Apr"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "05" {$mm = "May"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "06" {$mm = "Jun"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "07" {$mm = "Jul"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "08" {$mm = "Aug"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "09" {$mm = "Sep"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "10" {$mm = "Oct"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "11" {$mm = "Now"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
   "12" {$mm = "Dec"
        write-host "New mm is $mm"
}
    default
    {
      Write-host "The Month Duration $mmd  is not valid";continue
   }
 }
            $destination = "$base$Fname\$Fname-$year-$mm.zip"
            write-host " Destination $destination"
            Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"


function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )   
{
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
 $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,
    $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}
ZipFiles "$destination", "$source"

                  }

            start-sleep -s 1
                          }

}
```

## looks like the way of providing argument is not correct or the wild card placed in source is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateFromDirectory` doesn't allow wildcards. Use `Get-ChildItem` instead.

After the line

```
$source = "$base$Fname\$date*"
```

pass the matching files to a `foreach` loop:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem "$base$Fname\$date*")

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # ...
    # Continue with the rest of your code, starting at the line "$string = $date"
    # ...
    ZipFiles $destination, $file.FullName
}
```

Some other suggestions:

1. Move the `ZipFiles` function definition outside the `foreach` loops—it doesn't need to be redefined each time the loops run.
2. Move loading/importing `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` outside the `foreach`es as well.
3. Delete the entire `switch` statement and replace it with this: `$mm = [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName($mmd)`